# How do I receive the data from Google Form onto Google sheets and allow my students to edit it without other students seeing their work

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-forms

I am trying to feed data from a Google **Form** to a Google **Sheet**.  I want to have it separate each student into their sheet.  Then, I want to send that information back to the student in a Google Sheet so they can edit their work.

From what I understand, I can make A QUERY for each student on their own tab, but they will not be able to edit the tab.  So I researched and found out that I also need to IMPORTRANGE in order to share the Sheet so they can edit it.
EXAMPLE: I have tried this:

`=Query(Importrange("1w7lTxbg933A36rk0mNdqzaJn7KHAzXrvqekVXhh_BKM","Class January Work Log!A2:k"), "Select * where B = 'student's email address'")`

My error message is this:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: B

How do I receive the data from Google Forms onto Google Sheets and allow my students to edit it without other students seeing their work?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [AutoCrat](https://cloudlab.newvisions.org/autocrat). It lets you "merge" data received in a form response to cells in a spreadsheet. Each spreadsheet is created as a copy of a template spreadsheet that contains `<<tags>>` to show where to put each piece of data. The generated spreadsheets can be automatically shared and a link emailed to the person whose email address is in the form response.

To answer your `query()` question, try this:

```
=query( 
  importrange("1w7lTxbg933A36rk0mNdqzaJn7KHAzXrvqekVXhh_BKM", "Class January Work Log!A2:K"), 
  "where Col2 = 'student@example.org' ", 
  0 
)
```

Comment: What is this at the end?   ... 
  0 
)

Comment: The `query()` function takes three parameters. The `0` is the `headers` parameter that should always be specified to avoid surprises. But `query()` will not solve your problem, because formula results are not editable. Try AutoCrat.